# How to transform a category within a variable to be missing data?

Tags: r

Fruit is a categorical variable with levels: 0,1,2,3,4,5,NA

I want to code it so that NA is recognised in r as missing and not a level, so when I perform regression NA is not adjusted for.

Comment: `forcats::fct_explicit_na`  maybe? Could you provide a sample of your data? Or just drop/impute missingness altogether? Here's what you could do with forcats: `forcats::fct_explicit_na(fruit,na_level = "Missing")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
levels(fctr)[levels(fctr)=="NA"]<-NA
```

Replace `fctr` with your actual vector. This will replace the level named "NA" (and all of its instances in the vector) with an actual `NA`.